# How to make a scheduled report take holidays into consideration?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is scheduled to be emailed out every Friday (weekly report. If the Friday falls on a holiday is there any way to make this report be emailed out on the Thursday instead, via having the holidays stored in a table or of a similar nature.

I guess the more appropriate question might be: is it possible to create a data-driven schedule in SSRS?

To be specific, all holidays would be user defined. Ideally stored in an SQL db. If the date that the report was meant to go out exists in this table than the report would be delivered a day earlier.

Comment: Define a holiday? Who's holiday? How often is your report generator running..

Comment: A holidy would be defined by me and stored in a table. The report runs weekly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting services cannot do that by default.

A workaround could be:

- Create a table with holiday's
- Create a weekly schedule for each report, setting Friday as the day to run
- Create a scheduled task in SQL server agent to run on each week start, which will check if there is a holiday in this week. If it is, it will update the DaysOfWeek of the Schedule table on your report server from 32 (friday) to 16(thursday), otherwise it will set DaysOfWeek value to 32 (default)

**Important: Backup before attempting any change on your report server database.**

Comment: Good Solution, I did not think of approaching it from this angle